# Cannot fit multilevel ordinal logit model using clmm

Tags: r, multi-level, ordinal, random-effects

I'm trying to fit a multilevel (random effects) ordered logit model using the **ordinal** package, but I keep running into this error:

```
Error in region:country1 : NA/NaN argument
```

Here's my simplified model. I'm regressing an indicator of happiness on a number of variables, including class, gender, age, etc. There are two nested levels: regions within countries.

```
library(ordinal)

# Set as factor
data$happiness <- as.factor(data$happiness)

# Remove NA
missing_country1 <- is.na(data$country1)
data <- data[!missing_country1, ]

missing_region <- is.na(data$region)
data <- data[!missing_region, ]

# Model
model1 <- clmm(happiness ~ age + gender + class + (1 | country1 / region),
  data = data,
  na.action = na.omit
)
```

I have removed all NA and NaN from both country1 and region.

Thanks,

Comment: It'd help people here if you shared some of your data with `dput(data)`. If the output from that is a lot, you can use `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, will do in future

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: it was because ordinal doesn't automatically convert the grouping variables to factor, so you need to do it manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you are going to post this as an answer, please add additional code to help others with the same problem (ie, how does one do it manually?)

Comment: Sure, you could do it like this for instance: `data$country1 <- as.factor(data$country1)` and `data$region <- as.factor(data$region)`. You would also need to make sure there are no NA and NaN values in either column, as the package doesn't remove them automatically